# How to get objects related to an "ancestor" through one of its "descendants"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, relationship, has-many-through, has-many

I have models related as follows:

```
Country 
  has_many :states

State 
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :counties

County 
  belongs_to :State
  has_many :municipalities
  has_many :cities, through: :municipalities

City
  has_many :municipalities
  has_many :counties, through: :municipalities 

Municipality
  belongs_to :county
  belongs_to :city
```

I'd like to be able to call @country.cities and have it return all the cities that belong to a country through its related objects.

Has anyone seen or written a good helper for this? or is there a conventional way of doing this? right now the best I've got is something like

```
  def country_cities(country)
    country.municipalities.each do |municipality|
      municipality.city
    end
  end
```

I'm open to the fact that I might be missing something simple, but I've been through the active record docs in detail, and it seems like active record uses the belongs_to helper when building SQL queries, so the has_many through relationship breaks the downward "chain", and you have to call back "up" the chain like this @country.municipalities.individual_municipality.cities

I'm looking for a more elegant/simpler solution

Related to the actual queries:
There's no municipality_id or county_id on cities because cities do not belong_to counties or municipalities. They have_many :counties, through: :municipalities

I want to query all cities that have_a_county through municipalities. By convention, cities should not have municipality_ids. If I assign one, I should be able to query the database for all cities that have_a_county like so:

I would like to

```
# find cities
SELECT  `cities`.* FROM `cities`

  # where municipality_ids match any of the returned municipalities. 
  INNER JOIN `municipalities` ON `cities`.`municipality_id` = `municipalities`.`id`

  #inner join may be wrong here. I'm not sure exactly what that does; I just mimicked the other queries' syntax assuming it will check the records in the 'assemblies' table for a quantity_id.

  # where county_ids match any of the returned counties. 
  INNER JOIN `counties` ON `municipalities`.`county_id` = `counties`.`id`

  # where state_ids match any of the returned states
  INNER JOIN `states` ON `developments`.`state_id` = `states`.`id`

    # where state.country_id = params[:id] 
    WHERE `states`.`country_id` = 1
```

The above query would require cities to have a municipality_id to work, but I'm a little worried I'll cause some weird behavior in active record by doing that.

Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One place to start might be nesting your `has_many :X, through: Y` associations. You can create as many of these a you'd like without messing with your database columns and they'll just provide helpers for you. For example, the following will buy you:

```
@country.states
@country.counties
@country.municipalities
```

I've shortened my example, but it could be extended in the same way to include cities:

```
Country 
  has_many :states
  has_many :counties, through: :states
  has_many :municipalities, through: counties

State 
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :counties

County 
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :municipalities

Municipality
  belongs_to :county
```

Comment: That's a nice clean idea, but the question is specifically how to get x.z where z has_many x through y, and x has many z through y. Should I edit the question title to be more specific about using the join object, or should I open a new question? (i'm still pretty new here, and I got a few down-votes after editing a previous question after I had received a response)